# why cant i start log4j (newbie)

Tags: mongodb, log4j, morphia

Im already running morphia over mongDb in eclipse win7 64bit.
reading about the log4mongo here:
http://log4mongo.org/display/PUB/Log4mongo+for+Java
following the steps but get this:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [com.google.code.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender].
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.code.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:326)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:123)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:752)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
        at LogTest.main(LogTest.java:6)
    log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "MongoDB".
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (LogTest).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have the log4j.properties in my eclipse bin folder(maybe wrong but get no response elsewhere).

This files are importet:
log4mongo-java-0.7.0.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
mongo-2.6.5.jar

This is the log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, MongoDB
log4j.appender.MongoDB=com.google.code.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender
log4j.appender.MongoDB.databaseName=appname   
log4j.appender.MongoDB.collectionName=log
```

Im also startet a mongo shell that's waiting for connections

here's the starter:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LogTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogTest.class);
        logger.error("Don't panic");
    }
}
```

this is working as expected

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change appender name.

"com.google.code.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender" -> "org.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender".

log4mongo-java-0.7.0.jar used this package.

Comment: I Changed to org.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender and i do use that log4mongo-java-0.7.0.jar. The error is gone yes. using MongoVue but cannot see the appname or any log ducument however. Maybe the free version of mongoVue only show one db

Comment: Document is here -> "https://github.com/RobertStewart/log4mongo-java/blob/master/log4j.properties.sample". But I can't explain mongoVue, sorry.